# Filtering a single column to two unique values

Tags: python, pandas

I have used `.loc` to filter my dataframe to two columns 'Worker' and 'Time Type'.

Example dataset

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Worker': ['Sam','Ben','Tom'], 'Time Type':['Full Time', 'Part Time', 'paert Tme']})
df

Worker  Time Type
0   Sam Full Time
1   Ben Part Time
2   Tom paert Tme
```

I now want to see an output of only those with 'Part time' or 'Full time'.

The code i've built thus far is:

```
df2 = df.loc[:, ['Worker', 'Time Type']]
df2[(df2['Time Type'] == 'Part time' | 'Full time')]
```

However I am getting the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'`

Does anybody know an easy way to get around this?

Ideally I want to end up with two things:

1. An output showing Full Time and Part Time employees.
2. Another output showing anomalies outside of this parameter, i.e. 'Tom' in row 2 shows 'paert Tme' which is an anomaly and worthwhile viewing as a separate output.

Any tips on best practice or approaches would be excellent help, thanks folks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.isin()` function, much easier and nicer to read

`df[df['Time Type'].isin(['Full Time', 'Part Time'])]`